# How to write Unit test for views custom plugin with Drupal 8?

Tags: view, phpunit, drupal-8

Hi Im writing a Unit test for my custom module with drupal 8 please let me know how we can write Unit test for custom viewField plugin Class.

need to pass the entity for ResultRow Class as _entity parameter.

```
$result = $this->prophesize(ResultRow::class);
$result->_entity->willReturn((object) ['question' => 'sample question']);
$build = $component->render($result->reveal());
```